# Player is not responding to arduino code in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am developing this game (as part of a larger game), where the player has to collect all the coins before moving on to the next level. I want the player to  when it receives a set number of button clicks from an arduino. Every level requires a different amount of presses. So, for example, level 1 requires 1 click, level 2 requires 2 clicks etc. The issue here is that the player isn't responding to the input and I do not know why. When i tested this code using the space key, the player moved so the issue is definitely somewhere between the player and the arduino. Also, sometimes I press the buttons twice and the Arduino outputs 3 instead of 2, sometimes I press the buttons once and the Arduino outputs 2 instead of 1. Any tips on how I can fix these issues will be very appreciated.

This is the Arduino script:

```
  #include <Bounce2.h>
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// Connect each button with one connection
// to GND and the other to a digital pin.
const byte buttonPin = 2;
const byte buttonPin2 = 3;

class Button{

  private:

    byte m_buttonPin;
    byte m_counter = 0;
    unsigned long m_buttonPressTimeout;
    unsigned long m_previousMillis;

  public:

    Button(byte buttonPin):
      m_buttonPin(buttonPin),
      m_counter(0),
      m_buttonPressTimeout(2000), // Button press timeout in ms.
      m_previousMillis(0){}

    void Update(){
      if(m_counter > 0 && millis() - m_previousMillis >= m_buttonPressTimeout)
      {
        //Serial.print("Count from Update() just before it's reset to 0 = ");
        Serial.println(GetCounter());
        m_counter = 0;
      }
    }

    void IncrementCounter(){
      m_counter++;
      if(m_counter > 4){m_counter = 4;}
      if(m_counter == 1)
      {
        m_previousMillis = millis();
      }
    }

    friend void IncrementCounter(Button&);

    void IncrementCounter(Button&){
      IncrementCounter();
    }

    byte GetCounter(){
      return m_counter;
    }

};

Bounce buttonOneDebouncer = Bounce();
Bounce buttonTwoDebouncer = Bounce();
Button ButtonOne(buttonPin);
Button ButtonTwo(buttonPin2);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  buttonOneDebouncer.attach(buttonPin);
  buttonTwoDebouncer.attach(buttonPin2);
  buttonOneDebouncer.interval(25);
  buttonTwoDebouncer.interval(25);
}

void loop(){

  // Call the Update function as fast as possible.
  ButtonOne.Update();
  ButtonTwo.Update();

  // Button one pressed.
  if(buttonOneDebouncer.update()){
    if(buttonOneDebouncer.fell()){
      if(digitalRead(buttonPin2) == 0){
        ButtonOne.IncrementCounter();
      }
    }
  }

  // Button two pressed.
  if(buttonTwoDebouncer.update()){
    if(buttonTwoDebouncer.fell()){
      if(digitalRead(buttonPin) == 0){
        ButtonOne.IncrementCounter(ButtonTwo);
      }
    }
  }
  /*if(digitalRead(buttonPin) == 0 && (digitalRead(buttonPin2) == 0))
  {
  Serial.println("9");
  }*/

}
```

This is the Player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class PlayerControllerb : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int level;
    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] private PlatformProvider platformProvider;
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("\\\\.\\COM4", 9600);
    //player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    private void Awake()
    {
        OnSceneLoaded();
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        print(level);
    }
    public void OnSceneLoaded()
    {

    }
    public void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        platformProvider = FindObjectOfType<PlatformProvider>();
    }
    public float Speed = 1;
    private int currentPlatformIndex;
    public Vector2 height;
    public float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

    string value;
    int amount;

    void Start()
    {
        if (!sp.IsOpen)
        { // If the erial port is not open 
            sp.Open(); // Open 
        }
        sp.ReadTimeout = 1; // Timeout for reading

        print(level);
    }

    void Update()
    {

        // if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && level == 1)
        //     GoToNextPlatform();

        if (sp.IsOpen)
        { // Check to see if the serial port is open 
            try
            {

                value = sp.ReadLine(); //Read the information
                amount = int.Parse(value);
                print(amount);
                //transform.Translate(Speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);  //walk

                //if (/*amount > 25f)*/Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))  //jump

                if (amount == 1 && level == 1)
                {
                    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //{
                    GoToNextPlatform();
                    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
                if (amount == 2 && level == 2)
                {
                    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //{
                    GoToNextPlatform();
                    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
                if (amount == 3 && level == 3)
                {
                    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //{
                    GoToNextPlatform();
                    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
                if (amount == 4 && level == 4)
                {
                    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //{
                    GoToNextPlatform();
                    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
            }
            /*GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector3
            (
                Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.x, xMin, xMax),
                Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.y, yMin, yMax)
            );*/

        }
    }
    [ContextMenu(nameof(GoToNextPlatform))]
    public void GoToNextPlatform()
    {
        currentPlatformIndex++;
        currentPlatformIndex = Mathf.Min(currentPlatformIndex, platformProvider.platforms.Length);

        GoToPlatform(currentPlatformIndex);
    }
    [ContextMenu(nameof(GoToPreviousPlatform))]
    public void GoToPreviousPlatform()
    {
        currentPlatformIndex--;
        currentPlatformIndex = Mathf.Max(currentPlatformIndex, 0);

        GoToPlatform(currentPlatformIndex);
    }
    private void GoToPlatform(int index)
    {
        //StopAllCoroutines();
        //StartCoroutine(MoveTo(platformProvider.platforms[index].transform.position));

        gameObject.transform.position = platformProvider.platforms[index].transform.position;
    }
    IEnumerator MoveRoutine(Vector3 target)
    {
        while (!Mathf.Approximately(0, Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target)))
        {
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position, target, Time.deltaTime * Speed));
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector3

                   (
                        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.x, xMin, xMax),
                        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.y, yMin, yMax)
                    );
    }
    void ApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (sp != null)
        {

            {
                sp.Close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is a picture of the console to show that the inputs are being registered
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntZPP.png). This is an image of one of the game levels:[game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svP4p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well somewhere you need to get the positions of these platforms from yes.

I would have a dedicated `PlatformProvider` in each scene

```
public class PlatformProvider : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here reference your platforms via drag&drop in the order you need
    public Platform[] platforms;
}
```

And put this on all platforms

```
public class Platform : MonoBehaviour { }
```

it doesn't have to do anything but is used for referencing them.

Then in your controller find the platforms e.g. evertime a new scene is loaded.

I'm simply assuming here that your controller is never destroyed but staying alive, otherwise you only need to set the `PlatformProvider` only once in Awake or via the Inspector and not set it on runtime at all.

```
public class PlayerControllerb : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] private PlatformProvider platformProvider;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        OnSceneLoaded();

        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        // If anyway there is a new PlayerControllerb on each scene 
        // remove Awake and OnSceneLoaded and simply set the reference in the Inspector.
        platformProvider = FindObjectOfType<PlatformProvider>();
    }
```

then you can simply get the next position from the platform like

```
    // Set in the Inspector in Units per second
    public float Speed = 1;

    private int currentPlatformIndex;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(ARDUINO_MAGIC)
        {
            GoToNextPlatform ();
        }
    }

    // Using this you can debug it in the context menu of the component without Arduino ;)
    [ContextMenu(nameof(GoToNextPlatform)>]
    public void GoToNextPlatform()
    {
        currentPlatformIndex++;
        currentPlatformIndex = Mathf.Min(currentPlatformIndex, platformProvider.platforms.Length - 1); 

        GoToPlatform (currentPlatformIndex);
    } 

    [ContextMenu (nameof(GoToPreviousPlatform))]
    public void GoToPreviousPlatform()
    {
        currentPlatformIndex--;
        currentPlatformIndex = Mathf.Max(currentPlatformIndex, 0);

        GoToPlatform (currentPlatformIndex);
    }
```

then for the movement I would use a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) instead of doing stuff in `Update`. Anyway whenever a `Rigdbody(2D)` is involved you shouldn't assign any transformation through the `Transform` component but rather through the `Rigidbody(2D)` and in **[`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)** in order to not break the physics. In a Coroutine this can be achieved by using [`WaitForFixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html)

```
    private void GoToPlatform(int index)
    {
        // Depends on your needs
        // You can either use a bool and ignore concurrent routines
        // or simply stop any running one
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(MoveTo(platformProvider.platforms [index].transform.position));
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveRoutine (Vector3 target)
    {
        while(!Mathf.Approximately(0, Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target)))
        {
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

            rigidbody.MovePositio (Vector3.MoveTowards(rigidbody.position, target, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input; I really do appreciate it. I am trying to implement the code but I got a ton of errors. So I have tried to fix most but there are still 3 left. 2 state: SceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'onSceneLoaded'. The last error states: 'Platform' does not contain a definition for 'position' and no accessible extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'Platform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have tried fixing these but with no luck @derHugo

Comment: Hello @derHugo, I have still not been able to resolve these errors. Any ideas? I have tried several things but the errors persist :(

Comment: 1. it has to be [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html); 2. The second obviously should access the `transform.position` like `platformProvider.platforms[index].transform.position` ...

Comment: So I used MoveRoutine instead of MoveTo to sort out that one error. The player wasn't moving at all, so I added GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse); to the line just above GoToNextPlatform(); in the Update function. So now, what its doing is going to the first platform and then not moving at all after that :( . I find this to be a fairly advanced problem for a novice like me; looks like I've bit off more than I can chew @derHugo